# Customizing Rich Text Editor to automatically link email addresses while editing

Tags: content-editor, richtext-editor, speak

While I know you can hook into the `item:save` command or override the `scSendRequest` method, is there a better way to automatically make email addresses self `mailto` link when entered? (think of MS word, it will link after spacebar is pressed when you type in an email address)

I'm not worried about the regex magic to make it happen, I'm more concerned about finding the hook into Sitecore.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with a WAF transformation or with JS?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this default functionality? :

[image]

that generates `mailto` link:

[image]

Comment: Not all. I'm trying to have it automatically create the link without needing to click through the menu. When you type a link into MS word it will automatically turn it into a link, I want the same thing with sitecore.